# Assigning each array object from a text file JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, string, inputstream, java.util.scanner

So here is my dilemma: I have a text file that includes a list of students and details attributed to them, like their student ID, their name, how many hours completed for the semester, their major... etc.. Here is how the file looks:

```
222545767
name
Computer Science
15
60
222123767
name name
Computer Science
12
45
222334111
first last
Information Systems
16
54
622909311
first last
Computer Systems
12
48
222766721
first last.
Telecommunications
45
144
222123456
first last
Mathematics
15
54
```

Now when I read in the text file, I want each of the students to be assigned to an array object. I'm pretty fuzzy on how to do this, but here is my code thus far:

```
public class Student
{

private int id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String major;
private int hoursCompleted;
private int gradePoints;
Student[] studentsArray = new Student[30];  

public Student()
{

}

public Student(int id, String firstName, String lastName,
        String major, int hoursCompleted, int gradePoints)
{

}





public void readStudentsfile(){
    String fileName = "Students.txt";
    Scanner inputStream = null;

    try
    {
        inputStream = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("error");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    while(inputStream.hasNextLine()){
        int id = inputStream.nextInt();
        String firstName= inputStream.next();
        String lastName= inputStream.next();
        String major= inputStream.nextLine();
        int hoursCompleted= inputStream.nextInt();
        int gradePoints= inputStream.nextInt();

        studentsArray[1] = new Student(id, firstName, lastName, major, hoursCompleted, gradePoints);
         // this part is not correct but is where I need to assign
         // all of the variables read from the file into array objects
    }
    inputStream.close();
}
```

Comment: Probably shouldnt put real names and what look like student ID numbers from Delaware Technical and Community College-Owens especially with Grade points. If I was one of those students Id be going to your boss

Comment: Sounds like you need to read about [constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) and [instance variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).